# how to give a URL field Link text?

Tags: apex, force.com

I have a URL field on my object, and i want it to display the "Link Text" not the actual URL, but I can't get the syntax right.

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/">Visit W3Schools</a>
```

FWIW, the goal here is to populating this by a **trigger.** The link text = record name and the url = ID

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try out the option of using a formula(Text) field.

Formula Value :  `HYPERLINK( My_Link__c , 'Click This', 'Self')`

`My_Link__c` can be your URL field which will contain the URL and replace 'Click This' with your own text. 
In your scenario, have another text field where you can populate the URL display text (i.e. `Display_Text__c`)

So formula can be modified as : `HYPERLINK( My_Link__c , Display_Text__c, 'Self')`

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange koushik. Usign the {} button in the editor you can make code & formulas stand out a bit. I've taken the liberty to do so in your answer.

Comment: I'm populating by trigger. that won't work

Comment: what exactly are you population via trigger? an object? can we see your code? normally a link is on a page, and a page pulls from a class/objects, not sure how you are doing this via trigger since a trigger doesn't exactly connect to a page.. more information is needed.

Comment: If I've got your question correctly you are trying to create a URL whose 'URL value' and Text will be populated via trigger.

Comment: You can update these two values in two separate custom fields and create another formula field to use these fields and construct a link.